# Jasper Report doesn't display distinct values for desired field

Tags: jasper-reports, duplicates, crosstab

I have a Report in Jasper and I want to print distinct values for username field (The query is returning the desired output --no username duplicate values) but the report is printing duplicate usernames:

current output

```
Username|OTHER VALUE
      1 | A
      2 | B
      3 | C
      2 | B
      5 | E
```

Desired output:

```
Username|OTHER VALUE
      1 | A
      2 | B
      3 | C
      4 | D
      5 | E
```

This is some relevant xml from the jrxml file:

```
<crosstab>
    <rowGroup name="username" width="80" totalPosition="End">
                <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                  <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{username}]]></bucketExpression>
                </bucket>
                <crosstabRowHeader>
                  <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                    <box>
                      <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textField>
                      <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="12" uuid="7b266b77-130f-4834-ae30-3c1ae25db54b"/>
                      <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                      </textElement>
                      <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{username}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                  </cellContents>
                </crosstabRowHeader>
</rowGroup>

 <columnGroup name="conversion" height="36" totalPosition="End">
            <bucket class="java.lang.String">
              <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{othervalue}]]></bucketExpression>
            </bucket>
            <crosstabColumnHeader>
              <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textField>
                  <reportElement style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="5" width="90" height="31" uuid="e8d6815d-12bb-4806-a441-9cf86243d27e"/>
                  <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                  </textElement>
                  <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{othervalue}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
              </cellContents>
            </crosstabColumnHeader>
            <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
              <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                <box>
                  <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
              </cellContents>
            </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
          </columnGroup>
</crosstab>
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you sort data (by username)?

Comment: yes, the data returned by the query is sorted by username. @AlexK